Restoring birth certificate in Germany
My grandmother was born in 1922 in the village of Bischderer in the Neumarkt region of Silesia in Germany (this area is now part of Poland). Her mother is a German – Gertrude Bukh (born 1894), and her father is a Russian prisoner of war from the First World War. In 1924 or 1925 the whole family traveled to the Soviet Union. In 1941, my grandmother, mother and brothers were expelled to northern Kazakhstan for ethnic reasons. Her German birth certificate was lost there. Unfortunately, the grandmother herself has already died.
Is there now a chance to use German archives to find documents that confirm my grandmother's birth and prove that she is German and native German, and which archive should I contact for this?
Is there any chance of finding my grandmother's relatives?
